# insert data from a csv file into sql server database using php

Tags: php, sql-server-2012

I am getting an error while inserting although my filename and location are properly set..Any solution?
Thanks in advance...Here are my codes:

```
// path where your CSV file is located
define('CSV_PATH','C:\xampp\htdocs\form');

// Name of your CSV file
$csv_file = CSV_PATH . "test.csv"; 


if (($handle = fopen($csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
   fgetcsv($handle);   
   while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
          $col[$c] = $data[$c];
        }

 $col1 = $col[0];
 $col2 = $col[1];
 $col3 = $col[2];

 $query = "INSERT INTO csvTable(ID,Name,city) VALUES ('".$col1."','".$col2."','".$col3."')";
 $params = array();
 $options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
 $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params, $options ); 
 }
    fclose($handle);
 }

echo "File data successfully imported to database!!";
//mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

> Error Message: Warning: fopen(C:\xampp\htdocs\formtest.csv): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\form\upload.php on line 15

Comment: Perhaps you missed the backslash before your CSV file name ? `$csv_file = CSV_PATH . "\test.csv";`

Comment: That's right. And you can quickly find the cause to this kind of problems by following this checklist : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0):

Add backslash('\') after `Form` in define value

```
define('CSV_PATH','C:\xampp\htdocs\form');
```

**Change TO**

```
define('CSV_PATH','C:\xampp\htdocs\form\');
```

> OR

Add backslash('\') before your CSV file name

```
// Name of your CSV file
$csv_file = CSV_PATH . "test.csv";
```

**Change to**

```
$csv_file = CSV_PATH . "\test.csv";
```

Comment: More generally, there is a checklist to troubleshoot this kind of problems : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory